# put data on excel with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "sheet"

grade = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"]

for lst in grade:
    for i in range(len(grade)):
        ws.cell(row=i+1, column=1, value=lst)

wb.save("list.xlsx")
```

in this case, i expect the data should be arrayed like [image1].
but the result is [image2].
i dont know what is wrong with my code..
Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm4Av.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaJGX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want, my friend:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "sheet"

grade = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"]

for i in range(len(grade)):
    ws.cell(row=i+1, column=1, value=grade[i])

wb.save("list.xlsx")
```

Comment: @김갱민 If this helped you please upvote and mark as correct answer so that I can get the credit.

Comment: You may want to look at [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) which would yield (index, value) at each iteration without the range and len calls.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thank you so much. I've never know that

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you step in the second for loop where you pu your grade into each cell, the value of i changes. You can use global variable for row count this way your rows won't be overwritten.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be more helpful to provide example code alongside your explanation.